# C# Make other button column cell unclickable when one of the cell is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

I had a GUI that have a datagridview with button column.

[image: Pic]

I set the button **enabled** property to false once I click on the button cell.

[image: Pic2]

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {                 
            DataGridView senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                //....
               DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btnClick = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
               btnClick.Enabled = false;
        
               //execude code
        
               btnClick.Enabled = true;
             }                                   
        }
```

My question is how I make the other cell unclickable also to prevent the code run when one of the button cell is clicked?

Comment: You need to call `.Enabled = false` on all the buttons then. That'll involve a loop of sorts.

Comment: can you elaborate briefly ?

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 The button column is in the datagridview in the program. Thus, all the button in that column is called "btnClick". Currently, the button cell is disable when I click on it. But the other cell is still enable just like the second picture. I want all the cell is disable so that user would not click on it and disturb the program that still in run.

Comment: @yancy - you seem to understand `(DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)dataGridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]`. What stops you using very similar code to disable and enable all of the buttons in the grid. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Something like: `foreach (var cell in senderGrid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().SelectMany(x => x.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewDisableButtonCell>())) cell.Enabled = false;`. Assuming you have a single column of that custom type. Otherwise append a `where` clause in the `SelectMany` scope to specify which `OwningColumn`.

Comment: @dr.null Thanks so much for the example. The problem is resolved.

Comment: @dr.null - Please post as an answer that the OP can then accept.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sure. sorry I commented because I didn't check the code. Just meant to hint the idea.

Comment: @dr.null - Questions are way more valuable on this site if they have accepted answers. Answers in comments don't count for much. Thank you for adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the cells of type `DataGridViewDisableButtonCell` to get or set their properties. To avoid repeating the same code, create a method to toggle the `Enabled` property.

```cs
private void SetEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    foreach (var cell in senderGrid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
        .SelectMany(x => x.Cells
        .OfType<DataGridViewDisableButtonCell>())) 
        cell.Enabled = enabled;
}
```

In case you have multiple columns of that type and you want to apply the change on a specific one, then you need to specify the target column:

```cs
private void SetEnabled(bool enabled, int columnIndex)
{
    foreach (var cell in senderGrid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
        .SelectMany(c => c.Cells
        .OfType<DataGridViewDisableButtonCell>()
        .Where(col => col.OwningColumn.Index == columnIndex)))
        cell.Enabled = enabled;
}
```

Using the method in your code:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = sender as DataGridView;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        SetEnabled(false);
        // Or
        // SetEnabled(false, e.ColumnIndex);

        //execude code

        SetEnabled(true);
        // Or
        // SetEnabled(true, e.ColumnIndex);
    }
}
```